# Does my initial inventory go on the inventory tracking sheet?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

I'm getting ready for my first Pathfinder Society game. My character is created and I have a blank inventory tracking sheet. The only left is to purchase my initial inventory.

Does my initial inventory go on the inventory tracking sheet? Or is this sheet only for tracking changes to my inventory during games?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It doesn't have to

The Inventory Tracking Sheet is only necessary to track purchases and inventory changes between chronicles. Your initial equipment doesn't have to be tracked because the cost of those items isn't important for society games.

From [Michael Brooks](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q18q?The-Inventory-Tracking-Sheet#1), Campaign Coordinator:

> There is a 25 GP threshold involved, where all items above that need to be listed in the ITS. Any item that is 1 cp to 24 GP does not need to be listed.